# System of higher-order ODE to apply Runge-Kutta

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, runge-kutta-methods

I need to apply the Runge-Kutta of order 4 method for solving this equation

$$ y''(t)=\sum_{k=1}^{5} \frac{u_{k}(s_{k}-y(t))}{\|s_{k}-y(t)\|} $$

where $y'(0)=(\cos(\pi), \sin(\pi))$ and $y(0)=(0,0)$.

$u_k$ is a known vector with 5 components and $s_{k}$ is also a known vector with 2 components. How do I turn this into a system that I can apply Runge-Kutta of order $4$ to?

Comment: y is a two component vector function and yes, n is supposed to be k, my bad!

Comment: Is there a reason why you write $(-1,0)$ as $(\cos\pi,\sin\pi)$? Do you know how to establish the first order system? See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47711186/rk4-python-explanation